# Help with understanding a sentence

Tags: meaning

Kindly explain what does "to it" relate to? I can't understand the exact meaning of the last part of the sentence.

> But those guys just don't care about the little things like we do—our "chicken" has an essence, a real life **to it** that nothing else out there does.

This text is about our future where people have to produce meat with the help of gene engineering http://www.eater.com/2015/9/16/9334459/dystopian-restaurant-chef-interview-new-york-future-week

Comment: Please use a more specific question title. The one right now does not describe your question at all, and would fit nine out of ten other questions on this site. Be specific.

Comment: Ok, next time I will)) thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'to it' expression used in this sense means 'intimately associated with' or (as here) even 'as [part of] its fundamental nature'. When 'it' appears, it refers to the obvious antecedent or deducible referent (here, the individualised-for-general chicken):

> 'Riding a bike? There's nothing to it.'
>
> 'There's more to it than that.' ['the issue we're discussing']
>
> 'I thought there was more to John than that.' [more (and, implied, better)  aspects of his character]